# How to perfectly work with images in python 3.8.3 with OS of Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

Simple noob question:
How to perfectly work with images in python 3?

I tried various ways to achieve the images loading for my python 3, but not worked.

My python program case 1:

```
#Testing
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Python Title")
#Testing GUI image
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
image_flower = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("an image of flower.png"))
label_flower = Label(image=image_flower)
label_flower.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Then, I got this for case 1:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

My python program case 2:

```
#Testing
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Python Title")
#Testing GUI image
import ImageTk, Image
image_flower = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("an image of flower.png"))
label_flower = Label(image=image_flower)
label_flower.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Then, I got this for case 2:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ImageTk'

My python program case 3:

```
#Testing
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Python Title")
#Testing GUI image
import matplotlib.pyplot
a=Image.open("an image of flower.png")
a.show()
window.mainloop()
```

Then, I got this for case 3:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

My python program case 4:

```
#Testing
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Python Title")
#Testing GUI image
import media
```

Then, I got this for case 4:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'media'

My info:
Python 3.8.3
Windows 10 Home
Dell Inspiron 5590
Definitely enough space in the disk or drive
Definitely have the .png image file in the same folder of the .py python file.

Comment: All these solutions require you to install additional python packages. [The official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) can tell you how. For PIL you would need to install Pillow and for matploblib you need to install matploblib.

Comment: Have you heard about `pip` ? in the terminal say `pip install PIL` or `pip install matplotlib`. If you want to work with `png` ONLY, you can do so within `tkinter` itself, by saying `img = PhotoImage(file="an image of flower.png")` and then `Label(root,image=img).pack()`

Comment: Nice! Images are imported into my window or panel now since I can transform all other image types like .jpg ,bmp, etc to be .png type! Great!

Comment: well whgat do you mean by perfect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out a way to solve my problem, and that is to use tkinter itself, PhotoImage function, only png files are fine for me, or at least enough, no need the pip install, since I couldn't even install that through cmd command prompt, but it said I have that pip installed already/initially.

Comment: Can you explain? Maybe I could help now